# Where to update the data regarding "total criminal antitrust" fines globally in $US and days?

Tags: data-request, international-economics

[Dasgupta, 2019](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/32/7/2587/5079300?login=true) have the data for Total criminal antitrust fines from 1990 up to 2012

> Total criminal antitrust fines increased from $107 million in 2003 to

> $1.1 billion in 2012, and total prison sentences increased from an

> annual average of **3,313 days in the 1990s to 23,398 days by the end of
> 2012.**

I am wondering where I can have the data up to **the year 2020 or 2021** ( the most recent year)

Comment: You should also check if the total fines data are adjusted for inflation.

Comment: From the paper cited, I hope there should be a source that convert all data to $US dollar and inflation will not really play a key role here, just data to show off the change that audience can have the feeling about the change over time.